# Try to import csv file to SQL, error saying that index list out of range? How to fix it?

Tags: sql, excel, import

I try to import excel data to sql. but error said that index list out of range? How to fix it?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the question...

Comment: What sql provider are you using? What steps are you doing to import the data?

Comment: What file type is you excel sheet saved as? (not the extension). Make sure you have the same number of headers/fields/columns in source and destination